# Predictive Modeling of Overseas Filipino Workers' Average Length of Stay: A Comparison of Linear and Poisson Regression Models

Tags: modeling, linear, poisson-regression, continuous-data, discrete-data

i want to find our average length of stay in months with a discrete values however the number of months in the dataset is up to 60 that we can treat as continuous. I would like to determine when is better to use poisson analysis and when is better to use linear regression analysis for predictive modeling?